# Node.Js Crypto - Sign and Unsign JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the following function to sign a JSON with a PrivateKey.

```
    function createSignature(policy, privateKey) {
        var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA1');
        sign.update(JSON.stringify(policy));
        return sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
      }
```

Is there a way to unsign/decode the result? I can only find the verify() class in the documentation. But this true/false result is not enough. I want to see the policy json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createSignature` function returns a *signature* of input. Main use of signature is to verify that original data is correct. It's not an encryption algorithm at all. So, answer to your question is "no", you cannot generated a text from a signature in general.